# Does play count data update on iTunes music is played on the iPhone?

Tags: itunes, ios, iphone

If I listened to a song on my iPhone does it update the value on my macbook's iTunes ? And vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply said: yes it does, as soon as you sync it.

Also see [this question/answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/241498/does-itunes-play-count-gets-increased-while-listening-with-ipod-iphone-ipad).